# Change product size in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, products

How to change product size in magento. For e.g the size of the product is different for different products. I want all the products to have same size. Kindly see the issue in the picture below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit list.phmtl and change the image size:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(306); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

as you see `->resize(306)` this will make the image width and height 360px you can change this to `->resize(150,200)` so width is 150px and height is 200px

Also before size you can add : ( in case you want to remove the white frame around the image which is added by magento after resizing )

```
->constrainOnly(false)
->keepAspectRatio(true)
->keepFrame(true)
->keepTransparency(true)
->backgroundColor(array(255,255,255))
```

for more information you can see http://astrio.net/blog/images-resize-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

To modify images size on Category Pages, navigate to `app\design\frontend\default\your_theme_number\template\catalog\product`

Open list.phtml file. Search for “**resize**” text

```
->resize (210);
```

change it to whatever you want for example:

```
->resize(150);
```

which leads to an image which is 150px height and 150px width.

Comment: I want every product to have same frame size be it anything